# Passing `ngModelOptions` through from a custom component to a contained native element

Tags: angular

I have a custom component (Angular 6) called `ppo-currency-field` with the following template:

```
<span class="display" tabindex="-1">{{formattedValue()}}</span>
<input #input class="input" type="number" [name]="name" 
    [tabindex]="tabindex" [readonly]="!!readonly || readonly===''" 
    [disabled]="!!disabled || disabled===''" [ngModel]="value" 
    (ngModelChange)="writeValue($event)" [ngModelOptions]="ngModelOptions">
```

My component code contains the line:

```
@Input() ngModelOptions: Object;
```

I'm using my component with:

```
<ppo-currency-field [ngModel]="data.planningHours.rate"
  (ngModelChange)="data.planningHours.rate = $event; recalc();"
  [ngModelOptions]="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" 
  [disabled]="!data.containsPlanning ? '' : null"></ppo-currency-field>
```

As you can see, I'm attempting to "pass through" the `ngModelOptions` from my custom component to the `input` element. But this doesn't work, because the update option is not being set to "blur"; in fact, no update seems to be happening at all anymore.

However, when I set the option on the `input` element *directly*, that works perfectly.

Why doesn't my pass-through work, and how could I implement it properly?

EDIT: the problem only occurs when I try to use `ngModelOptions` as the attribute name. If I change it to e.g. `options`, it works. This is ok I guess, but I was attempting to make my component behave as much as a native input field as possible. It makes intuitive sense that I shouldn't try to reuse an Angular directive, but in that case the `ControlValueAccessor` interface should offer a hook to catch these options, as it does for `ngModel`/`ngModelChange`.

Comment: What happens if you create the `{ updateOn: 'blur' }` object in the component class, instead of inline in the HTML?

Comment: Good thought - unfortunately, there is no change. EDIT: I did `testOptions = { updateOn: 'blur' };` in the declaration of the consumer component and used that in the consumer template, like so: `[ngModelOptions]="testOptions"`

Comment: Not sure if this is related, but it looks like you need a space here: `disabled===''"[ngModel]="value"`

Comment: @FrankModica Uh no, that came from my formatting, it wasn't present in the actual code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ngModelOptions` property at the custom component level applies to the ControlValueAccessor without having to bind the inner input element to a custom `@Input() ngModelOptions` property, as you can see in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-s9y69o).

In order for the `ngModel` of the custom component to update correctly:

1. The inner input element should update on change (the default option), to make sure that the ControlValueAccessor can also update on change.
2. For the `{updateOn: 'blur'}` option to work, the `onTouched` event callback of the ControlValueAccessor should be called when the input element loses focus:

```
<input ... 
  [ngModel]="value" 
  (ngModelChange)="writeValue($event)" 
  (blur)="onTouchedCallback()" />
```

where `onTouchedCallback` is set in the custom component:

```
registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
  this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
}
```

---

The explanation for the need to call the `onTouched` callback is given in a comment by [kara](https://github.com/kara) in [issue 20384](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20384) on Github:

> The `{updateOn: 'blur'}` functionality on the top level depends on the
>   control value accessor underneath it implementing `registerOnTouched`
>   properly. It looks like your custom component saves the callback, but
>   never actually calls it. Since it's not called, the value doesn't
>   update properly. I'd recommend adding a `(blur)="onTouchedCallback()"`
>   to your ControlValueAccessor and it should work.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @ConnorsFan! This works perfectly. It just appears a bit strange that Ng applies ngModelOptions to contained elements, but then doesn't capture the relevant events by itself?

Comment: You are welcome. I updated the answer. Actually, the `ngModelOptions` applies to the custom component, not to the inner input element. As long as the two conditions mentioned in the answer are met, the ControlValueAccessor can respond correctly to the `ngModelOptions` set on the component. The console messages in the stackblitz show that the inner input element does update on change, even when the ControlValueAccessor updates on blur.